# Partition postgreSQL over multiple docker containers

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, partitioning

I'd like to understand how could I partition a postgreSQL DB.
Lets say I have 2 docker containers of PostgreSQL and the table contains {id , name}.
I want to partition names starting from [a-h] in the first container db.
and other names starting from [h-z] in the second container db.

Also How would I retrieve the data?

Comment: That's called "sharding" and I don't know if PostgreSQL can do that out of the box.

Comment: @TheImpaler Do you know how to implement it on my own??

Comment: In general, a traditional PostgreSQL database in a container (I would assume you have persistence) won't talk to other PostgreSQL containers. You would probably need to modify your app to know about all the containers and their purposes (a-h or i-z) and the direct the calls to each one appropriately. Maybe there's a sharding solution for PostgreSQL but I don't know about it. These guys are improving the engine a lot recently, so it wouldn't suprise me if I see it at some point.